# Is a unary relation a set of single elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My doubt arised from the sources below.

> Such a class is what we call a binary relation, or just relation.

> We will not use the terminology "unary relations"; rather we will just call them classes (or sets, as the case may be)

(Tourlakis, 2011, p. 194) **$[1]$**

> A unary relation on a set x is a subset of x

(Devlin, 1979, p. 13) **$[2]$**

### Question:

The definition of a relation I learnt is: a relation is a set of ordered pairs obtained by the association between two sets, which is a subset of their cartesian product.

Now, assuming a unary relation is a set, then the definition I've stated applies for only binary relations?

In summary, I have two questions:

1. Is an unary relation a set?
2. Do some authors use the term relation to mean binary relations?

### References:

**$[1]$**: Tourlakis, G. (2011). Lectures in Logic and Set Theory: Volume 2, Set Theory (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, Series Number 83) (1st ed.). Cambridge University Press. [URL](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=nparMXao59QC&pg=PA194&dq=Unary%20relation%20is...%20set%20theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjoufvvssXwAhVOhOAKHc5cBhUQ6AEwCHoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=Unary%20relation%20is...%20set%20theory&f=false)

**$[2]$**: Devlin, K. (1979). Fundamentals of Contemporary Set Theory. Springer. [URL](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=4FHtBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&dq=Unary%20relation%20is.%20.%20.%20set%20theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjoufvvssXwAhVOhOAKHc5cBhUQ6AEwBHoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=Unary%20relation%20is.%20.%20.%20set%20theory&f=false)

Comment: Generally, relations, without any further context, refer to binary relations. Unary relations aren't very common, although there is a simple identification of a unary relation with a subset of the set. A unary relation is always a set though.

Comment: It should be mentioned that *all* objects in mathematics under most set theories are themselves sets, including binary relations.  Just because it happens to be a set *of ordered pairs* doesn't stop it from from being a set.  About the only exceptions to that I know of are *classes* and *urelements* if the set theory you use allows for such things.

Comment: If binary relation is a set of ordered pairs, then analoguously a unary relation is a set of single elements.... in other words .... a subset.  And that's really all there is to say about it. I wouldn't sweat it or lose any sleep over it.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. What I meant by an unary relation being a set was that it only contained elements that aren't pairs, sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I$ and $X$ are sets, recall that $X^I$ is the set of all functions $f\colon I\to X$. When $I=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, we often think of $X^I$ as a set of $n$-tuples; the connection is that the $n$-tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ corresponds to the function $f\colon\{1,\ldots,n\}\to X$ given by $f(i)=x_i$. In this case, we say the relation is an $n$-ary relation.

Likewise, we may express an $I$-tuple in the form $(x_i)_{i\in I}$, where $x_i$ is the image of $i\in I$ under the element.

If $I$ and $X$ are sets, an $I$-ary relation on $X$ is a subset $R$ of $X^I$. We say an $I$-tuple $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ is in the relation $R$ if and only if $(x_i)\in R$.

For example, for real numbers, we can define a $3$-ary relation $IB$, "in between", where we say $(x,y,z)\in IB$ if and only if $y$ is strictly between $x$ and $z$ (that is, $x\lt y\lt z$).

Generally speaking, binary (i.e., $2$-ary) relations are among the most common relations, so we use the "naked" term "relation" to refer to binary relations, unless explicitly stated otherwise. The definition you quote is the definition of a *binary* relation. While we often refer to binary relations by just saying "relation", we almost never refer to *other* types of relations without specifying the index set.

A unary relation would then be a $1$-ary relation. Technically, that means a subset of $X^1$; but it is easy to see that there is a natural bijection between $X^1$ and $X$, identifying $(a_1)$ with just $a_1\in X$, and hence that $1$-ary relation, subsets of $X^1$, are naturally identifiable with subsets of $X$. So in a sense, unary relations "are the same" as subsets of $X$.